# Making a computer turn itself on, check for updates and then shut down automatically

Tags: windows, automation, automatic-update

My mother lives in another city, and she has a desktop computer (Windows 10) that she rarely uses. It stays off for probably 360 of 365 days of a year.

But when she finally decides to use the computer, it always has Windows updates that will install automatically while she uses the computer... Which causes some problems: First, it makes the computer slow, and second, it asks for restarts.

She always complains that her computer is slow and therefore avoids using it, which makes things even worse.

The computer, in fact, is okay... It's a 6th gen i5 with 8GB RAM and a 500GB SSD. It works fine for office and internet stuff.

It would be nice if the computer could just turn itself on (once a week maybe?), check for updates (and install the updates if any), then at the end, turn itself off.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Some Bios'es have a scheduled wake function (mine does) that would allow you to turn the computer on. I think you can set when windows checks for updates, finally you can probably create a cron to shut it down.

Comment: Windows 10 does more than Windows updates.  It can do firmware updates as well which require attention.  You would be better to get a remote startup device so that you could start it, access it and do all updates and then shut it down

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is set to sleep, rather than to shutdown, you may schedule
a task to periodically wake up the computer at night, check and
install updates, and reboot if required.
The task will use PowerShell for the job.

I don't advise to do that if the computer is located where it can
wake somebody up when it powers back up. Also, test it well.
I note that some rare Windows updates may cause problems which your
mother may not know how to fix.

This is the way to do this :

- In PowerShell, download and install the module
  [PSWindowsUpdate](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.3)
  with this command :

  ```
  Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
  ```
- Import the module : `Import-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate`
- Use Task Scheduler to create a task to be run at certain days and
  hours, that will run a PowerShell script that executes this command:

  ```
  Install-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
  ```
- To put the computer back to sleep, use the command
  [shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)
  (not immediately for the scheduled task to terminate gracefully).

Some useful reference :

- [PSWindowsupdate: Automated Windows Updates with PowerShell](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2023/06/pswindowsupdate-automated-windows-updates-with-powershell/)
- [Manage Windows Updates with PSWindowsUpdate PowerShell Module](https://woshub.com/pswindowsupdate-module/)

Comment: If you set the computer to sleep or hibernate, Windows will automatically turn on the computer at night to install windows updates, and reboot. The only thing it won't do is turn it back off again. If you create a batch script or powershell script to run powercfg -lastwake and you run that at startup, you can find out if the computer was turned on because of windows updates.

Comment: @LPChip: I'm not sure that Windows will turn on the computer in order to *search* for updates, or just does it in order to install updates that it previously detected when the computer was on. Note: I missed out in my answer that the script should return the computer to sleep.

Comment: Ever since I switched from turning off my computer to using hibernation, I had the problem at every now and then, I would find my computer turned on in the morning. At first I just was like, hibernate again and no biggy. Then there was an update that failed to install, and every morning my computer was turned on. This made me dig into the whole issue and I discovered there are scheduled tasks present for doing this. They can be found at \Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate, and one of them is called ScheduledStart. Its trigger is set to when you hibernate the computer.

Comment: Also, powershell's command `start-sleep` will not actually put the computer to sleep, it just delays execution of the script. Because the command has the word sleep in it, one is probably going to assume that this is the command to hibernate the computer, which is not the case.

Comment: @LPChip: Strange I never noticed this happening with my computers. I might inadvertently have set some setting that blocks it (or just never had the luck to wake up at the right time). Thanks for pointing up my error with `start-sleep`, maybe it's time to sleep for me too.

Comment: I do not think I would leave a computer suspended or hibernated 350 days to use for the remainder of 365 days.  I truly believe a remote starter is the way to go here.

Comment: A remote starter would require me to manually take care of this task... And I wish to just not have to think about it ever again.